# python - ssh command output to a variable is different from screen

Tags: python

Does anyone know why a ssh command output to the screen and to a variable is not the same?
my meaning is when the command output direct to the screen it's and when i save it to a variable and then print the variable is not the same output:

**to the screen:**

```
s.sendline ('uptime')
s.prompt()
print s.before
s.logout(
```

**output:**

```
uptime
 09:52:40 up 170 days, 16:20,  4 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.02, 0.00
```

**to a variable:**

```
running = s.sendline ('uptime')
print (running)
```

**output:**

```
7
```

i'm really don't understand where the '7' comes from and why i got to different outputs?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try `paramiko` module?
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.sendline):

> sendline(s='')
>
> Wraps send(), sending string s to child process, with os.linesep automatically appended. Returns number of bytes written

Comment: OK, sow how can i get the output variable and use if for other needs?

Comment: You could redirect stdout, what do you want to do with the output?

Comment: The output will be in s.before, as in your previous example.

Comment: lets say that the output it's a name of a  direcotry and then i would like to enter to that directory.